# How to convert multiple vector layers to georeferenced rasters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, spatialite

I have Openstreetmap background loaded in QGIS - currently from Spatialite, but no problem to get shapefiles.

I need to convert the loaded map to one big raster or could also by more smaller ones, but surely need them to be georeferenced.

I know there are ways to convert native OSM files to raster but I am also using custom styling as Stamen Tonerlite or [Google style](http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/) and have no idea how to apply them outside QGIS.

My current idea about "dirty" solution is about switching off north arrow and other decorations in QGIS, then using "Save as image" to produce multiple georeferenced images to cover my area and finally merge them into one using Gdal tools from QGIS.

But maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS print composer in > 2.6 can create georeferenced output as described in https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#creating-output

> If you need to export your layout as a georeferenced image (i.e., to load back inside QGIS), you need to enable this feature under the Composition tab. Check [checkbox] **World file on** and choose the map item to use. With this option, the ‘Export as image’ action will also create a world file.

Therefore it's not necessary to use "Save as image" to manually save multiple smaller maps.